# Do Deutsche Bahn ICE trains to Belgium require a reservation?

Tags: international-travel, germany, belgium, deutsche-bahn

I booked a trip from Hamburg Hbf to Brussels/Bruxelles Midi, entirely with Deutsche Bahn trains. Later, I got an email from Deutsche Bahn stating the following:

> Due to a timetable change, your journey from Hamburg Hbf to Bruxelles Midi on 02 February 2024 cannot be carried out as described. Click "Get current information here" for alternative journey options to your destination.
>
> The requirement for you to travel on a specific train on your booked connection has been lifted. This means you can also use your ticket on other Deutsche Bahn long-distance trains (e.g. ICE/IC/EC), as well as local trains and S-Bahn trains.
>
> Please note that you must book a new reservation if your connection requires one (e.g. trains to France).

While this is nice, what's confusing to me is the last section where it states that I must book a new reservation if my connection requires one, with the example being trains to France. Does this apply to the itinerary I'm making, where I'm planning to exclusively use Deutsche Bahn trains? For going from Germany to Bruxelles Midi I'm planning to get on an ICE train in Köln/Cologne, specifically (there are no direct trains from Hamburg Hbf to Bruxelles Midi).

Comment: Travelling to FOSDEM?

Comment: @user253751 Yes, I was, but this is not the place to talk about that :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> In einigen Zügen ins Ausland gibt es eine Reservierungspflicht. **Die
> Reservierung ist dann bereits kostenfrei im Ticket enthalten.** Die
> Reservierungspflicht gilt für folgende Züge:
>
> - Hochgeschwindigkeitszüge (ICE und TGV) nach Frankreich (Paris und Marseille)
> - Züge nach Schweden
> - Züge nach Italien
> - Züge nach Polen
>
> https://www.bahn.de/faq/reservierungspflicht-flexpreis-europa

> On some trains abroad, you are required to reserve a seat. **This reservation will already be included in your ticket.** The requirement exists on the following trains:
>
> - high speed trains (ICE and TGV) to France (Paris and Marseille)
> - trains to Sweden
> - trains to Italy
> - trains to Poland

If you search for such connections, they'll be marked by an " Reservierungspflicht" on [bahn.de](http://bahn.de). Your Bruxelles Midi train that I checked did *not* appear with that mark.

Comment: Note for future readers: some international ICEs do require reservations in summer.  I don't know what happens if DB force travellers onto other trains if reservation-mandatory trains are cancelled.

Comment: @gerrit Apparently [if it's an ICE and the cancellation was known at least an hour in advance, your reservation is automatically transferred.](https://www.bahn.de/faq/erhalte-ich-bei-jeder-zugaenderung-eine-neue-sitzplatzreservierung) But only if it's the exact same route, not some other route or train. And no idea what that means for TGVs or other trains, probably SOL. More fun FAQs: https://www.bahn.de/faq/pk/angebot/sitzplatzreservierung.